# should we use Path.DirectorySeperatorChar C#

Tags: c#, .net, string

A question that's lurking in my head for a while now.
What's the importance of Path.DirectorySeperatorChar ?
I mean can't we just put '\' instead - which i think is faster than calling a property 
especially if you're constructing a huge number of paths in your application?
Is there a reason for it? could there be another Char for folder/file path seperation other than '\' ? maybe in another operating system?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, use the property. It will be more future-proof. You will be compatible with Mono (Linux) but MS.NET may also move to other platforms (like Compact and Micro Framework).

But the best method is to use `Path.Combine()` and `Path.GetFileName()` et al, and then you won't be needing the separator char at all.

Comment: THanks a lot for the compatibility issues. Didn't know that

Answer (score 3):

Use `Path.Combine()` for combining paths. Unfortunately, it's not as fast as it could be since the `Path` class' methods operate on `string` instead of a special struct (`Path` as a non-static class, perhaps?). Why is this a problem you ask? This gem:

> **Exceptions:**
>     `ArgumentException`  *path1* or *path2* contain one or more of the invalid characters defined in `GetInvalidPathChars`.

Comment: No! no problem, i'm just asking for the performance optimization.
But you said, 'it's not as fast as it could be'. The question is, is it theoretically faster than the normal string concatenation of the path.
I mean, which is faster?
Path.Combine() or directory1+Path.DirectorySeperatorChar+dir2.

Comment: `Path.Combine()` doesn't duplicate the separator if one is present at the end of `directory1` and/or the beginning of `directory2`. That said, manual implementation of the option would be significantly/measurably faster if you have to perform the operation thousands of times on the GUI thread. It probably wouldn't ever be a problem for background processes/tools, and certainly wouldn't for a "small number" of operations (hundreds or less).

Answer (score 1):

On linux, separator is /. And we do have Mono there.

Answer (score 1):

Windows accepts / for path separators does it not? Just use that to be compatible. However, the combine method is better to use.

Answer (score 0):

To make the code compatible with other platforms, such as Unix, which uses forward slashes for path separator. I believe there are also some special corner cases in Windows itself, such as with device driver paths.

A clarification on Josh's answer: Windows *generally* accepts forward slash for path separators, but not every Windows application does, and there might be some places that Windows doesn't either. For example, on the command line forward slash usually introduces a parameter. So I would not personally rely on this.

I agree however, that it is quite verbose for something you want to use often in some situations. In my own (Delphi) code I used to use a method "AddSlash" which added a slash, if necessary, of the right kind. One could imagine a new language symbol or character constant that decoded to the right char for the platform.